# I want to classify the occurrence event

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have the following dataset that indicates my Bike travels:

```
time    Event   Occ
10:00   Moving  1-moving
10:10   Parked  1-parked
10:12   Moving  2-moving
10:30   Moving  2-moving
11:00   Moving  2-moving
11:05   Parked  2-parked
11:07   Moving  3-moving
```

Event indicates if the bike is *moving* or if it is *parked*.

I need to add one calculated column: the column `Occ` which indicates the `Event` occurrence. In the above table you can see my expected result.

I tried to use Rowid() without success.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for is the following:

```
Concatenate(Integer(1 + Sum(If([Event]="Parked",1,0)) OVER (AllPrevious([time])) - (If([Event]="Parked",1,0))),"-",[Event])
```

---

Explanations:

- Count the number of *Parked* event before the current row:

`Sum(If([Event]="Parked",1,0)) OVER (AllPrevious([time]))`

- Add one because the first row starts at `1` and not `0`

`1 +`...

- The parked event must have the same number than the previous moving

...`- (If([Event]="Parked",1,0))`

- To have an `integer` instead of a `real` (because the result of `Sum` is a `real` number, and this type is kept after other operations with `integer`)

`Integer(`...`)`

- To add the  `-` and the name of the *Event*

`Concatenate(`...`,"-",[Event])`